# Is there an appropriate way to say that "my posts need to be revised"? (For ESL clarity)

Tags: discussion, edits, non-english-speakers, english

Before I ask this question, I searched and found no similar question.

I'm not a native English speaker, but I try my best to express what I mean with my questions and answers.
I wish that my questions and answers would be more helpful to people in the future, and I'm worried about causing misunderstandings. For example, I have this question that needs revision:

- [How to find the minimum covariant type for best fit between two types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472103/how-to-find-the-minimum-covariant-type-between-two-types)

I think that it would not be appropriate to post on Meta, every time I need this kind of favor. I thought about *chat*, but I'd rather just let people know I need help -- if someone has time and is willing to.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Good that you make the effort and ask here instead of "posting and forgetting" like most other users but I fear there's no standard way of marking a post as "needing a revision". Just try to learn from the edits you get and with time your English will improve. I also come from a different country and English isn't my native language, yet I believe I reached a good level of using it. It's all matter of effort and time.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Thank you. I think all StackExchange site are for HelpExchange, and I'd like to make things helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly state that English is not your first language and maybe say something like, "Edits to correct grammar are appreciated".

But, I think what you did on [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472103/how-to-find-the-minimum-covariant-type-between-two-types):

- at least 26 edits!
- question(s) on Meta
- responding to comments
- offering a bounty

Are all good ways to improve the question.
That kind of "stick-to-it-iveness" is 90% of the battle, IMO.

Don't discount Chat, though.  It can be a good back-channel to "pre vet" a question for grammar, before you ask it, or to explicitly ask for an editorial review.  It doesn't have quite the overhead of a meta question either -- which might get redundant for this kind of thing.

Comment: Does *"doesn't have quite the overhead .."* mean that if sometimes I need this kind of favor, it's not too bad to post on Meta if I've tried for other ways?

Comment: I would try chat first.  It's okay to post on Meta, but beware of creating "too localized" or "duplicate" questions.

Comment: I've added to state that as your suggestion. Thank you very much.